# Is there a specific strategy which one should take while playing Puggle, or should you just drop the pugs and hope for the best?

Tags: pewdiepie-tuber-simulator

I know that each game of Puggle is somewhat random as to where the bubbles are and what the two dog bowls have, but is there a strategy which can help get better scores and thus quicker shipping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No the only thing you could do is to find a "perfect" spot where the pug will be falling into one of the two bowls. The Points are generated randomly.

Comment: I know that, but of those perfect spots, which ones would hit the most pegs and/or pass by the most places the bubbles will be?

Comment: You have to try it on your own, there are million ways to do this, its all about luck(and maybe math callculation)